# Cannot load gulp: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory 'node-sass/vendor'

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, sass, gulp

Having this problem for hours now and can't solve it:

```
Cannot load gulp: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/ME/mywebsite/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
```

Weird thing is, the node-sass module is in my files **(I checked) and reinstalling, rebuilding or removing does not work at all**. It just keeps giving me the same errors when I try to start up `gulp sass` to transform my SCSS to CSS.

I am out of options, as I have tried everything I could find on SO and Google.

Is there something I am missing?

**PS:** using Ionic. Please see my configurations:

```
[WARN] Bad integration name: gulp
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 master
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 1.0.8

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (9 plugins total)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.0
   ios-sim    : 5.0.8
   NodeJS     : v6.8.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 2.15.11
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incredible, but I fixed it by adding a folder manually to the node-sass folder.

I was triggered by this comment: https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/issues/7758#issuecomment-230465352

Damn it! Hope that it helps someone.

After that, I did `npm rebuild node-sass` and it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a npm install node-sass and it created the folder, like it missed it on the first install.